# convert DCOM to JPG

Tags: php

I need to convert DCOM image into JPG image, I'm using `class_dicom.php` from [this site](http://deanvaughan.org/wordpress/dicom-php-class/).
But I can't save converted image in my `var_dump()`. The following is the response:

```
object(dicom_convert)#1 (5) {
    ["file"] => string(62) "img/dcom/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.634.0.12779.2012316.9235.11.dcm"
    ["jpg_file"] => string(66) "img/dcom/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.634.0.12779.2012316.9235.11.dcm.jpg"
    ["tn_file"] => string(69) "img/dcom/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.634.0.12779.2012316.9235.11.dcm_tn.jpg"
    ["jpg_quality"] => int(100)
    ["tn_size"] => int(125)
}
```

So, as I understood, in `jpg_file` I have saved(?) JPG image, or not? If not, how can I save it?

because if I use

```
$jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost/'.$d->jpg_file);
imagejpeg($jpg, NULL);`
```

I had an error

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(http://localhost/img/dcom/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.634.0.12779.2012316.9235.11.dcm.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in O:\home\localhost\www\dcm_to_jpg.php on line 29

Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in O:\home\snimki\www\dcm_to_jpg.php on line 30
```

So can anyone halp with my question?

**UPD1:**

Ok, as I can see, I can't save the converted image, and so I can't access the file which not exists... So I have second question, can anyone help me to save converted JPG picture which I get from `class_dicom.php` class... I just can't find there function for saving file...

Comment: emmm, and why this question get minuses?

Comment: `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found `

Comment: @SLaks emmm, by which URL?

Comment: `http://localhost/img/dcom/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.634.0.12779.2012316.9235.11.dcm.jpg`

Comment: @SLaks That's just localhost! Obviusly 404 for you & me n all! He is testing the script in his system.

Comment: @JensonMJohn that is the error the op is getting when trying to run the script. check if the image is location is correct because the script cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try with this.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo file_get_contents($imgPath); //$imgPath -> img/dcom/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.634.0.12779.2012316.9235.11.dcm_tn.jpg
```